# ConcurentModificationException

Tags: java, android, exception

this piece of code throws ConcurentModificationException. This is in i function called update witch is a part of an Android game and it is called 60 times/minutes (I think that is the problem but IDK):

```
List<Bullet> blts = robot.getBullets();
        if (blts.size() > 0 && enemys.size() > 0) {
            Iterator<Bullet> it_b = blts.iterator();
            Iterator<Enemy> it_e = enemys.iterator();
            while (it_e.hasNext()) {
                Enemy e = it_e.next();
                it: while (it_b.hasNext()) {
                    Bullet b = it_b.next();
                    if (b.getRect().intersect(e.getRect())) {
                        e.degreesHealth(20);
                        it_b.remove();
                        if (e.getHealth() <= 0) {
                            it_e.remove();
                            break it;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

if it is importan, here is the whole class: http://pastebin.com/R4rX7DBY

Comment: Are the `blts` or `enemys` lists accessed anywhere else from your code at the same time?

Comment: You can't modify the size of an array (or iterator) while iterating through it.

Comment: @TylerOlson That's not true. There's a reason `Iterator#remove()` exists, and that's so you *can* modify something while iterating through it.

Comment: You didn't post the whole code but from what you've put on `pastebin`, you might wanna try moving the start of your `Thread` `MyThread` after you have loaded the map and entities, I think iterating a list that get object added is what cause your error.

Comment: @user3580294 It's designed to only be called once per next though, it's being called possibly more than once per next here.

Comment: @NESPowerGlove I was just saying it *is* possible to modify a collection while iterating through it. You're totally right with the once per `next()` caveat.

Comment: Right, I think I meant _shouldn't_, but that doesn't necessarily hold true either. I had this error when two threads accessed the same array simultaneously and made changes.

Comment: @user3580294 Oh yeah I misread the comment sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You started the MyThread thread before calling other methods on the main thread of the program. Therefore, while the main thread is populating your lists, the MyThread thread is trying to access and remove items from the lists... You cannot concurrently modify the lists like this, I recommend, loading everything, THEN starting MyThread.

You can initialize the Thread, `MyThread` wherever you want in your code, but make sure you load all of your lists, and then start it. Otherwise you will be trying to remove and add items at the same time, which doesn't work.

`Thread mythread = new MyThread();` can be put anywhere before your start call

Where as the start call `mythread.start` must be put after all of your methods that load items into your lists.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

You iterate through your enemys.iterator() `it_e`, and while you do that, you are remove an element from it with `it_e.remove();` possibly more than once.

The javadocs of Iterator say you can only call `remove()` once per `next()`, but since you are calling `it_e.remove()` in an inner loop (`while (it_b.hasNext())`), you are possibly calling `it_e.remove()` multiple times per `it_e.next()` from the parent loop (`while (it_e.hasNext())`).

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29)

Comment: Even if this is true, there's nothing in the question that make this useful. No where in the code the OP provided, pastebin included, this might happen.

Comment: Well it's definitely a bug to have the ability for remove() to be called twice, and this is the only apparent bug in the initial code supplied. I don't have access to pastebin at the moment, but I'd imagine if it's a game and the Bullet and Enemy object's values are impacted by the user actions that there's no way for sure to avoid not calling remove twice.

Answer (score 0):

A common workaround to all the iterator and ConcurrentModification hassles would be to collect all the enemies and bullets to be removed into Lists, then remove them all in one shot afterwards.  It also, IMO, makes the code way simpler and easier to read.

```
List<Enemy> deadEnemies = new ArrayList<Enemy>();
List<Bullet> usedBullets = new ArrayList<Bullet>();
for (Enemy e : enemys) {
   for (Bullet b : bullets) {
      if they intersect {
         if enemy is out of health then 
            deadEnemies.add(e);
         usedBullets.add(b);
      }
   }
}

// iteration is now done, so much lower chance of a ConcurentModificationException
    enemies.removeAll(deadEnemies);
    bullets.removeAll(usedBullets);
```

One minor difference is that a bullet could kill multiple enemies, and an enemy could use up multiple bullets, if they are allowed to overlap.  Since bullets and people are [Fermions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermion), this isn't really possible, but, depending on your computer math, maybe it can happen in your virtual world...  :-)